# How do I compare pairs within a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, nltk

I'm trying to loop through a concatenated list of two lists that is essentially a bag of words - example outputs yields [('brexit', 11), ('say', 11), ('uk', 7), ('eu', 6), ('deal', 5), ('may', 5), ..., ('brexit', 35), ('say', 28), , ('may', 5), ('uk', 1), ... ]

Having gathered all the text inputs from .txt files, I've removed the stop-words and using stemming to remove duplicated from tenses.

The next step I want to take is to loop through the list and find the differences in the number of appearances a given word - I would want 'brexit', 'say' and 'uk' to be flagged as significant words with either the two numbers of appearances or just the difference. My start of the code (partly python, partly pseudocode) is below.

```
def findSimilarities (word, count):
    for (word, count) in biasDict:
        if word == word and count != count:
            print (word, count - count)
        elif word ==word and count == count:
            del (word, count)
        (word, count)++
```

Any advice on how to approach this and edit the code to work? If it would be better, I can have the words come from two separate lists (which is how they are created; I concatenated them after they were created).

Many thanks.

Comment: In your list of tuples, is there a single occurence of every word, or more than one occurence?

Comment: Some have one occurrence, others have two occurrences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be an option. Not efficient, but the output is as desired. That is, if you want to delete word's with the same count (as shown in your code). If you want to keep the entries, just skip the biasDict.remove() part.
If your just interested in the word's that occur twice with a different count, you could append the tuples to a new list instead of printing the difference. Afterwards return the new list.

```
import numpy as np

def findSimilarities (biasDict):
    similarities = {}
    #remove_later = []
    for i in range(0, len(biasDict)):
        word, count = biasDict[i][0], biasDict[i][1]
        for c in range(0, len(biasDict)):
            word_compare, count_compare = biasDict[c][0], biasDict[c][1]
            if c==i:
                pass #Same entry
            elif word == word_compare and count != count_compare:
                delta = count - count_compare
                if word not in similarities and delta != 0:
                    similarities[word] = np.abs(delta)
            #elif word == word_compare and count == count_compare and (word, count) not in remove_later:
            #    remove_later.append((word, count))
    #for entry in remove_later:
    #    biasDict.remove(entry)
    return similarities
biasDict =  [('brexit', 11), ('say', 11), ('uk', 7), ('eu', 6), ('deal', 5), ('may', 5), ('brexit', 35), ('say', 28), ('may', 5), ('uk', 1)]
print(findSimilarities(biasDict))
```

Output:

```
{'brexit': 24, 'say': 17, 'uk': 6}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Would you have any advice on just achieving the first part of the output without the full biasDict also being returned? I'm fairly new to Python. Thanks

Comment: So you only want to have a list with words appearing more than once with a different count? If so, as i've stated in the answer, you can declare a new list, append the difference and return this list. I edited my answer in such a way. 
But be careful, right now only the case of two appearances works. If a word appears three times, only one similarity will be extracted.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of combining occurrences seems fine for me. Here is my implementation. Any comment or optimization is appreciated.

```
def merge_list(words_count_list):
updated_list = list()
words_list = list()
for i in range(len(words_count_list)):
    word = words_count_list[i][0]
    count = words_count_list[i][1]
    if word not in words_list:
        words_list.append(word)
        for j in range(i+1,len(words_count_list),1):
            if word == words_count_list[j][0]:
                count += words_count_list[j][1]
        updated_list.append((word,count))
return updated_list

print(merge_list([('brexit', 11), ('say', 11), ('uk', 7), ('eu', 6), ('deal', 5), ('may', 5), 
                                                ('brexit', 35), ('say', 28),('may', 5), ('uk', 1)]))
```

output:

```
[('brexit', 46), ('say', 39), ('uk', 8), ('eu', 6), ('deal', 5), ('may', 10)]
```

Now, you can specify a threshold on the word count, sort by the count, then remove the most significant words.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two lists of the words, then you can do

```
#Converts list of tuples to dictionary.
#[('a',1'),('b',2)] => {'a':1,'b',2}
def tupleListToDict(list):

    dictobj = {}
    for item in list:
        dictobj[item[0]] = item[1]
    return dictobj

def findSimilarities(list1, list2):
    dict1 = tupleListToDict(list1)
    dict2 = tupleListToDict(list2)
    dict3 = {} #To store the difference
    #Find occurence of key in 2nd dict, if found, calculate the difference
    for key, value in dict1.items():
        if key in dict2.keys():
            dict3[key] = abs(value - dict2[key])
    return dict3
```

Example output

```
list1 = [('brexit', 11), ('say', 11), ('uk', 7), ('eu', 6), ('deal', 5), ('may', 5)]
list2 = [('brexit', 35), ('say', 28), ('may', 5), ('uk', 1)]
print(findSimilarities(list1, list2))
{'brexit': 24, 'say': 17, 'uk': 6, 'may': 0}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure, for future, create your bag of words as [('brexit', [11,25,16])....] which will make the code much easier.

Comment: Is there a way to stop the words with a 0 difference from being included in the list? So that the output of 'print(findSimilarities(list1, list2))' would just be {'brexit': 24, 'say': 17, 'uk': 6}? And what about including examples like ''deal', 5' in the output too which only appear in one but are 'significant'? Many thanks